# VueJS change a table's row in a loop individually

Tags: javascript, user-interface, vue.js, html-table

I'm struggling to wrap my head around the logic behind this:

I'm using *VueJS* to show some records from a database in a table, and to show it dinamically, so filtering, pagination etc, also, I want that when I click on a row, it acts like a clicked button and change its `background-color`, then it should "slide up" to show the row's complete content (so like a complete reactive UI), but let's focus on the background-color change:  The content is in the table, Vue loads everything it got from my endpoint and shows it, I made the class `.selected`, and edited the v-for loop on the `tbody` binding the selected class to a `selected` variable, then on click firing up a function to change the variable true\false value.

The problem is, if I click a row every row's color change because they all share the same class name and triggering it on one one triggers it for every row.

Since I didn't share any code yet, here's the tbody in all its glory, I won't type the Vue instance cause it's pretty simple : one variable in *data* (`selected = false`), and one function in *methods* (`isSelected`).

```
<tbody v-for="(post, key) in posts" :key="post.id">

        <tr @click="isSelected()">
          <td><strong>@{{ post.id }}</strong> </td>
          <td>@{{ post.PID }}</td>
          <td>@{{ post.title }}</td>
          <td>@{{ post.slug }}</td>
          <td>@{{ post.content.substr(0,50) }}</td>
          <td>@{{ post.status }}</td>
          <td>@{{ post.likes_count }}</td>
          <td>@{{ post.comments_count }}</td>
          <td>@{{ post.publish_date }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

How do I approach this? I was thinking about making the class name dynamic so it's `selected-N` where N is the row's index, but it doesn't seem like the right solution.

How would you do it? How do you handle multiple looped data editing using VueJS? Cause after this one, I want everything in that table to be responding to the user's actions (changing color like a button so you know which row is selected, sliding up\down for showing informations and\or more options etc..).

**Edit :**

Following Husam's suggestion:

I've changed the v-for part

```
<tbody v-for="(post, key) in posts" :key="post.id">

        <tr @click="selected(key)" :class="{ selectedRow: post.selected }">
```

I've checked with some alerts, and the key is correctly passed to the selected function, which is this :

```
selected: function (key) {
        this.posts[key].selected = !this.posts[key].selected;

      } // end function
```

Also when I get the objects from the api call I create the selected property,
which effectively toggled in the correct object when I click the row, the problem is, the color doesn't change, so the class binding `:class="{ selectedRow: post.selected }"` is not toggling the class when I click, is `post.selected` the correct data to give? (selectedRow class in already created and changed the background color)

**Adding more infos in case anybody else ends up here :**

As suggested in the comments, adding `this.$forceUpdate()` to my `selected(key)` function fixes the problem :

```
selected: function (key) {
        this.$forceUpdate();
        this.posts[key].selected = !this.posts[key].selected;
      } // end function
```

So what'd the issue here?

Comment: have you tried passing unique key as parameter `selected(key)` ?

Comment: @Deda the only thing isSelected() function does is changine the selected value from false to true and vice versa, I could pass the key but doing what with it?

Comment: How did you bind class on each row, with classic way? `.tr {... } ?`

Comment: Add a `selected` property to each individual post. Then use [dynamic class binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes) to assign a class on each row based on the post's `selected` value.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim I've tried what you suggested Husam, I edited the original post, please take a look

Comment: make an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: @K3nzie Check if this is a reactivity issue first by calling `this.$forceUpdate()` in your selected function. If it is we can look for some remedy. Otherwise something else is wrong and the selected values aren't being assigned/accessed properly.

Comment: @A.Lau I've made one example here https://codesandbox.io/s/zlmx93m38m apparently it's working, so something's bad with my code, but I can't figure out exactly what. Also I've added the this.$forceUpdate() in my selected function and now it's working!! Why is that so? What's the issue here?